# glutPostRedisplay calls display method but doesn't redraw window

Tags: opengl, cuda

I'm writing a program to graph 3D surfaces. It uses CUDA to do rendering and then OpenGL to display the results. It works fine and renders pretty and accurate results, but it does not correctly update the window. Here's my program in pseudocode:

```
void display() {

   //render stuff

   glutSwapBuffers();


   glutPostRedisplay();
}

int main() {

  //set up OpenGL and CUDA

  glutMainLoop();

  return 0;

}
```

This should update continuously, but it doesn't. It correctly calls the display method and CUDA renders the results, but it does not display the results in the window until the window is resized. So it calls the display function something like 30 times a second, but the window doesn't actually show the results until resized or minimized.

Here's my entire program. It's EXTREMELY messy and has no comments since I was learning OpenGL as I went along.

```
#define GL_GLEXT_PROTOTYPES

#include <GL/freeglut_std.h>
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glext.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cuda_gl_interop.h>

#define XSIZE 1280
#define YSIZE 640

float theta = .15;
float phi = 1;
float r = 10;
float3 lightDirection = make_float3(9, 5, -5);
float delta = .001;

GLuint pbo;     // OpenGL pixel buffer object
struct cudaGraphicsResource *cuda_pbo_resource; // handles OpenGL-CUDA exchange
GLuint texid;   // Texture
GLuint shader;

__host__ __device__ float3 operator+(float3 a, float3 b) {
    return make_float3(a.x + b.x, a.y + b.y, a.z + b.z);
}

__host__ __device__ float3 operator-(float3 a, float3 b) {
    return make_float3(a.x - b.x, a.y - b.y, a.z - b.z);
}

__host__ __device__ float3 operator*(float3 a, float b) {
    return make_float3(a.x * b, a.y * b, a.z * b);
}

__host__ __device__ float3 operator/(float3 a, float b) {
    return make_float3(a.x / b, a.y / b, a.z / b);
}

__host__ __device__ float operator*(float3 a, float3 b) {
    return a.x * b.x + a.y * b.y + a.z * b.z;
}

__host__ __device__ float magnitude(float3 a) {
    return std::sqrt(a * a);
}

__host__ __device__ float3 normalize(float3 a) {
    return a / magnitude(a);
}

__device__ float valueAt(float3 a) {
    return std::sin(a.x) + std::sin(a.y) + std::sin(a.z);
}

__device__ float3 normalAt(float3 a) {
    float x = valueAt(make_float3(a.x + .001, a.y, a.z)) - valueAt(a);
    float y = valueAt(make_float3(a.x, a.y + .001, a.z)) - valueAt(a);
    float z = valueAt(make_float3(a.x, a.y, a.z + .001)) - valueAt(a);
    return make_float3(x, y, z) / .001;
}

__device__ float estimateDistance(float3 a) {
    return std::abs(valueAt(a) / magnitude(normalAt(a)));
}

__device__ float3 trace(float3 from, float3 direction) {
    float totalDistance = 0;
    float3 v = from;
    for(int steps = 0; steps < 256; steps++) {
        if(magnitude(v) < 5) break;
        totalDistance += 1;
        v = from + direction * totalDistance;
    }
    for(int steps = 0; steps < 256; steps++) {
        v = from + direction * totalDistance;
        float distance = estimateDistance(v);
        totalDistance += distance * .1;
        if(distance < .1 && magnitude(v) < 5) return v;
    }
    return make_float3(0, 0, 0);
}

__device__ uchar4 colorAt(float3 v, float3 lightDirection, float3 viewDirection) {
    float3 normal = normalize(normalAt(v));
    float3 h = normalize(viewDirection + lightDirection);
    float specular = std::abs(std::pow(h * normal, 15)) * .5;
    float diffuse = std::abs(lightDirection * normal) * .5;
    float lighting = (specular + diffuse) * .9;
    lighting += .1;
    float3 color;
    if((fmod(v.x + 1000, 1) < .5 && fmod(v.y + 1000, 1) < .5) || (fmod(v.x + 1000, 1) > .5 && fmod(v.y + 1000, 1) > .5)) {
        color.x = 1;
        color.y = .5;
        color.z = .25;
    }
    else {
        color.x = .75;
        color.y = .5;
        color.z = .25;
    }
    color = color * lighting;
    return make_uchar4((unsigned char)(color.x * 255), (unsigned char)(color.y * 255), (unsigned char)(color.z * 255), 255);
}

__global__ void eval(float3 position, float3 direction, float3 right, float3 up, float3 lightDirection, float delta, uchar4* dev_pixels) {
    int x = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    int y = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
    int offset = x + y * XSIZE;

    float rAngle = (x - XSIZE / 2) * delta;
    float uAngle = (-y + YSIZE / 2) * delta;

    float3 rayDirection = direction + right * rAngle + up * uAngle;
    rayDirection = normalize(rayDirection);
    float3 v = trace(position, rayDirection);
    uchar4 color;
    if(magnitude(v) != 0) color = colorAt(v, lightDirection, direction);
    dev_pixels[offset] = color;
}

void display() {

    uchar4* dev_pixels;

    cudaGLRegisterBufferObject(pbo);
    cudaGLMapBufferObject((void**)&dev_pixels, pbo);

    dim3 dim_block(16, 16);
    dim3 dim_grid(XSIZE / 16, YSIZE / 16);

    float3 position = make_float3(std::cos(theta) * std::sin(phi) * r, std::sin(theta) * std::sin(phi) * r, std::cos(phi) * r);
    float3 direction = normalize(position) * -1;
    float3 right = make_float3(-std::sin(theta), std::cos(theta), 0);
    right = normalize(right);
    float3 up = make_float3(-std::cos(phi) * std::cos(theta), -std::cos(phi) * std::sin(theta), std::sin(phi));
    up = normalize(up);

    eval<<<dim_grid, dim_block>>>(position, direction, right, up, lightDirection, delta, dev_pixels);

    cudaGLUnmapBufferObject(pbo);

    glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, pbo);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texid);
    glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, XSIZE, YSIZE, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glTexCoord2f(0.0f,1.0f); glVertex3f(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
    glTexCoord2f(0.0f,0.0f); glVertex3f(0.0f,1.0f,0.0f);
    glTexCoord2f(1.0f,0.0f); glVertex3f(1.0f,1.0f,0.0f);
    glTexCoord2f(1.0f,1.0f); glVertex3f(1.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
    glEnd();

    glutSwapBuffers();
    theta += .01;
    glutPostRedisplay();
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    lightDirection = normalize(lightDirection);

    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DOUBLE);
    glutInitWindowSize(XSIZE, YSIZE);
    glutCreateWindow("Grapher");
    glutDisplayFunc(display);

    glViewport(0, 0, XSIZE, YSIZE);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0, 1.0f, 0, 1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.5f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glGenBuffers(1, &pbo);
    glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, pbo);
    glBufferData(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, XSIZE * YSIZE * 4, NULL, GL_DYNAMIC_COPY);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glGenTextures(1, &texid);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texid);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB8, XSIZE, YSIZE, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

    glutMainLoop();

    return 0;
}
```

I'm using NSight Eclipse on Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 3):

At the end of your `display` routine, add these 2 lines:

```
...
glTexCoord2f(1.0f,1.0f); glVertex3f(1.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
glEnd();

glutSwapBuffers();

glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);                      // add this line
cudaGLUnregisterBufferObject(pbo);                 // add this line

theta += .01;
glutPostRedisplay();
...
```

The first addition allows the animation to proceed frame by frame. (Frames after the first will render properly.)

The second addition makes it so that if you close the animation window, you won't get a seg fault.  `cudaGLUnregisterBufferObject` must be called on any previously registered object before the underlying OpenGL resource gets freed (or else you get a seg fault).  When you click the X to close the window, the OpenGL buffer object (`pbo`) gets freed as the OpenGL context disappears.

Comment: Works like a charm. I'm not entirely sure what glClear does, though. Does it reset the buffer so it can be written to again? It works, though, so now I just need to clean up and finish the project.

Comment: The basic documentation for `glClear` is [here](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glClear.xhtml).  It is used to clear one or more of several buffers.  The depth buffer contains Z information (ie. depth information) about each pixel in the framebuffer (i.e. in the buffer that your pixel buffer is getting drawn to.)  If you're drawing a new scene (which effectively you are, each frame) it's important to clear this first.  You may want to learn more about rendering with depth, for that try [chapter 10 of the OpenGL redbook](http://glprogramming.com/red/chapter10.html).